# How does subtraction work in the Hack VM?

Tags: nand2tetris

I'm taking the Nand2Tetris course on Coursera, the one where we translate VM Bytecode to asm, and I'm a bit confused on how the `sub` opcode is supposed to work in Project 7.

Assuming I've got code that looks like this

```
push constant 5
push constant 7
sub
```

I'd expect the output to be 2, but its -2 instead.

7 was the last thing pushed onto the stack, and I'm assuming the first thing popped off it, but it wasn't the first "argument" to `sub`? Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

This is just the way two-operand stack operations are defined to work. The way to visualize it is that the operator is moved between the two numbers.

This system also makes it much easier to convert from normal notation, since all you have to do is move the operators, not reorder the numbers.

For example, (1+2)/(4-3) becomes 12+43-/

Comment: I was going to implement this using a simple Python list, since it already has .append() and .pop(), but with this spec for sub() it seems like I'd need to .pop() twice to get the top two elements of the stack, [7, 5], reverse that list THEN pass it to sub? Or is my approach wrong in the first place?

Comment: The simple way to do it, following the explanation in Chapter 7 is to pop the two values into two temporary variables, do the computation, and push. But you can get sneaky and do the final operation directly on the stack, saving a pop and a push. So if you are doing 43-, the code becomes something like (from memory):

`@SP     // Pop SP (assuming SP grows down)`
`AM=M+1 // now (SP) and A BOTH point to 2nd parameter (4)`
`D=M  // D=2nd parameter`
`@SP  // Access 1st parameter, but don't pop!`
`A=M+1 // A points to 1st parameter`
`M=M-D // Subtract 2nd parameter from first`